# Could someone please help me convert the following Strategy to Study

Tags: pine-script

I am basically looking for setting alerts for Long Trail Stop and Short Trail Stop. The following strategy is in Version 3. Hence need this to be converted to Study in Version 4. Also I would really appreciate if any one can please share a similar study for Trailing stop loss (% of instrument price).
Your kind help is much appreciated in advance!

```
//@version=3
strategy(title="Trailing stop loss (% of instrument price)",
     overlay=true, pyramiding=3)

// STEP 1:
// Configure trail stop level with input options (optional)
longTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Long Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01

shortTrailPerc = input(title="Trail Short Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=3) * 0.01

// Calculate moving averages
fastSMA = sma(close, 20)
slowSMA = sma(close, 60)

// Calculate trading conditions
enterLong  = crossover(fastSMA, slowSMA)
enterShort = crossunder(fastSMA, slowSMA)

// Plot moving averages
plot(series=fastSMA, color=teal)
plot(series=slowSMA, color=orange)

// STEP 2:
// Determine trail stop loss prices
longStopPrice = 0.0, shortStopPrice = 0.0

longStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    stopValue = close * (1 - longTrailPerc)
    max(stopValue, longStopPrice[1])
else
    0

shortStopPrice := if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    stopValue = close * (1 + shortTrailPerc)
    min(stopValue, shortStopPrice[1])
else
    999999

// Plot stop loss values for confirmation
plot(series=(strategy.position_size > 0) ? longStopPrice : na,
     color=fuchsia, style=cross,
     linewidth=2, title="Long Trail Stop")
plot(series=(strategy.position_size < 0) ? shortStopPrice : na,
     color=fuchsia, style=cross,
     linewidth=2, title="Short Trail Stop")

// Submit entry orders
if (enterLong)
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true)

if (enterShort)
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false)

// STEP 3:
// Submit exit orders for trail stop loss price
if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XL TRL STP", stop=longStopPrice)

if (strategy.position_size < 0)
    strategy.exit(id="XS TRL STP", stop=shortStopPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a good enought coder (yet) to help you with the code itself, but I found a tutorial for a %-based trailing stop:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azms_Kqq3EI

Hope it helpes somewhat at least :)

Edit:
Oh, and check this one out, it may work.

https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000530720-how-can-i-convert-v3-scripts-to-v4/